# Cucumber Testing for Windows Application built in .NET

Tags: .net, cucumber, bdd

I know Cucumber and Web application testing with Watir and Watir-webdriver, but I need to know how to use Cucumber for Windows application, specifically application built in .NET.

Any direction on how to get started? Which gem to use? Tips? Etc.. ?

P.S. I am a guy who used to work in QTP before Cucumber and in QTP we would change the plug-in from Web to .NET and it would recognize window application objects like Edit Box, Menu Item...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could start to automate the Winforms interaction with something like [White](http://white.codeplex.com/).  This requires you to write .NET code to drive it though, so integrating with Cucumber could be tricky.  You may be able to run Cucumber under [IronRuby](http://ironruby.net/), and then your step definitions could directly access the White API.  Alternatively you could look at one of the .NET variants of Cucumber such as [SpecFlow](http://specflow.org/), which still uses Gherkin as the language for writing features, but you write step definitions in pure .NET, or [Cuke4Nuke](https://github.com/richardlawrence/Cuke4Nuke) which actually uses Cucumber to execute your features, but talks to a .NET assembly containing your step definitions.

Comment: So, does it mean that we don't have any ruby gem which can be just imported for .net (like watir-webdriver for web)?

Comment: I wouldn't like to say for certain, but I don't think there is such a thing.  Libraries for driving winforms projects certainly exist for .NET so I think your only option will be to get your step definitions executing .NET code, using one of the projects I linked to.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.. I would vote this as the answer to my question and close the question, I think I got what I was looking for. I was looking for a RubyGem or in its absence a setup or idea on how I should design framework to test .Net application.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at http://specflow.org/

Comment: Thanks! It looks nice, I am working on it to see how I can incorporate with what I already have in Cucumber